# how to use play and pause in html5 for SWF format?

Tags: html, html5-video, shockwave

I am having a `SWF` file. I need a Play and Pause button for that UI.  I tried to use `<video>` tag but its not working.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="899" height="199" id="tech" align="middle">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
  <param name="movie" value="ApparelVideo.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <embed src="ApparelVideo.swf" quality="high" width="899" height="199" name="tech" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

**Note:**  Play and pause should be onclick function like after loading the webpage onclick on video it has to play, it has to stop in the second onclick on video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't play SWF-files using HTML5 video, because Flash isn't one of the supported video codecs (well, it isn't even a video codec).

[HTML5 video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) is meant to play videos without using vendor specific plugins – which are required to play Flash objects.

in the last ten years a myriad of Flash video players was created and can be found online.

Comment: So how to use Play and pause in SWF Format ?